# Read specific section from ini

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code where I have successfully read the sections and their corresponding values from ini. Now I'm trying to output the results that meet certain conditions only but having some issues to get the correct output, hope to get some ideas how I can do this

```
ini file -
[Issue_1]
close_major = some jql
#contains all problems with major priority

[Issue_2]
close_minor = some jql
#contains all problems with minor priority
```

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('test.ini')

    result = dict()
    for section in config.sections():
        ticket_results = list()
        result[section] = ticket_results
        for desc, jql in config.items(section):
            results = jira.search_issues(jql, startAt=0, maxResults=1000)

            for i in results:
                dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+0000'
                ticket_end_time = datetime.strptime(i.fields.customfield_xxx, dateformat)
                ticket_start_time = datetime.strptime(i.fields.customfield_zzz, dateformat)
                issue_time = ticket_end_time-ticket_start_time
                issue_time_new = issue_time.total_seconds()

# Try to get the issues where issue time is less than 2days for Issue_1 and 5days for Issue_2
                if(config.items('Issue_1')):
                    if issue_time_new < 172800:
                        ticket_results.append(i.key)
                elif(config.items('Issue_2')):
                    if issue_time_new < 432000:
                        ticket_results.append(i.key)
print(result)
```

Looks like I'm not looping this correctly, assuming the correct output should be 5 results for Issue_1 and 4 for Issue_2

I'm getting 6 results for Issue_2 because it is reading the ini section from Issue_1 instead of Issue_2

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and single stepping through line by line?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out where I did wrong -

Instead of using if(config.items('Issue_1')), should just use section in this case... so the code should look something like this...

```
if 'Issue_1' in section and issue_time_new < 172800:
    ticket_results.append(i.key)
```